# Regex password requirements

Tags: c#, regex

I can't tell you how much I hate imposing password restrictions, but alas, my boss made it mandatory. I need a regular expression that satisfies the following:

- At least 8 characters
- A mix of uppercase and lowercase characters
- At least 2 numbers

This is what I have got so far, but it seems to satisfy only one condition:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?=.{8})(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])", ErrorMessage = "Password must contain at least 8 characters, a mix of uppercase and lowercase, and 2 numbers.")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: *I can't tell you how much I hate imposing password restrictions...* so you hate securing your data against attackers? I'm not really sure what to make of this statement.

Comment: I think the password should be left to the user. Imposing restrictions make it easier to crack.

Comment: *"Imposing restrictions makes it easier to crack."* Do you have a source on this? This would blow the entire IT Security community out of the water. Why do you think password restrictions exist in the first place? I will not extend this discussion any longer as it is outside the scope of the question, but **please** keep security in mind. It's effectively the only thing between an attacker and data they have motivation to exfiltrate.

Comment: Strict rules provide hackers with a template — they know not to bother trying passwords which are less than 8 characters, more than 20, have less than 2 numbers, etc. Moreover, it (usually) makes the password harder to remember. This is assuming that the user knows how to choose a decent password for themselves (e.g. avoiding "password" as their password).

Comment: *"Imposing restrictions makes it easier to crack."* I also give a +1 on that. No source of course. But complex passwords make users to write them down.

Comment: *"This is assuming that the user knows how to choose a decent password for themselves (e.g. avoiding "password" as their password)"* - this is exactly why your boss is creating requirements for passwords, because users *can't* be trusted to know to create secure passwords.

Comment: +1 You have a point. In my opinion, users should be allowed to choose whatever password they want. You can show a warning message when an easily-broken password is entered but, heck if you can't trust users to enter a decent password, don't let them choose one: create a random string and post it to them via email or snail mail (kidding).  Anyhow, I figured out a solution to my problem, will post it in a sec.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/936/  :-)

Comment: Hahaha that comic is gold. Nice find! :)

Answer (score 2):

Using only lookaheads `(?=)`, Perl syntax:

```
^(?=.{8})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d.*\d)
```

Comment: Did you mean `^(?=.{8})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d.*\d)` (you forgot one `?=`) ?

Comment: Nice and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way with custom attributes:

```
    public class CustomPasswordAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                var password = value.ToString();

                if (password.Length < 8)
                    return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);

                var hasUpperCase = false;
                var hasLowerCase = false;
                var numDigits = 0;

                foreach (var c in password)
                {
                    if (char.IsUpper(c))
                        hasUpperCase = true;
                    else if (char.IsLower(c))
                        hasLowerCase = true;
                    else if (char.IsDigit(c))
                        numDigits++;
                }

                if (!hasUpperCase || !hasLowerCase || numDigits < 2)
                    return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
[CustomPassword(ErrorMessage = "Password must be at least 8 characters in length, contain both uppercase and lowercase characters, and at least 2 numbers.")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```